# How to use TableViewCell from xib file on UITableView with no Reusable feature in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have this UITableViewCell from a .xib file
[image]

And I'm using it on a UITableViewCell inside of a storyboard with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [requestTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RequestAcceptTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"RequestAcceptCellIdentifier"];
    requestTableView.estimatedRowHeight=168;
    requestTableView.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    [requestTableView reloadData];
    requestTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [requestArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    RequestAcceptTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RequestAcceptCellIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RequestAcceptTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                 reuseIdentifier:@"RequestAcceptCellIdentifier"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

so far this works good:
[image]

But I want this to stop reusing UITableViewCells everytime I scroll on my UITableView since I just want to have there a maximum of 5 UITableViewCells inside, I tried with:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    RequestAcceptTableViewCell = [[RequestAcceptTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                                     reuseIdentifier:nil];
    return cell;
}
```

and then I get this:

[image]

My UITableView has a UITableViewCell with no format, buttons, labels... is there a way to call a UITableViewCell by it's identifier but without reusing it?? I mean, keeping it in memory...

thanks for the support

Comment: Use initwithnibname instead

Comment: do you have an example? because I put the following on my custom UITableViewCell class 'RequestAcceptTableViewCell':     

- (id)init

{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"RequestAcceptTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // Further initialization if needed
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Initialize with -init");
    return nil;
}               and I get following message: No visible @interface for 'UITableViewCell' declares the selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:'

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to reuse UITableViewCell, you have to:

- Use `Static Cells` instead of `Dynamic Prototypes`.
- Set number of rows to 5 on: storyboard -> Table View -> Table View Section -> Rows : 5.
- Remove all data source methods (`numberOfRowsInSection` & `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) -> **IMPORTANT**.
- Drag and drop `IBOutlets` from storyboard to your implementation file.
- Then you can configure your labels/buttons/views from their referenced IBOutlet.

**Update:**

If you wish to have the `Dynamic Prototypes` you could do this:

Remove this line:
RequestAcceptTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RequestAcceptCellIdentifier"];

Add this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    RequestAcceptTableViewCell *cell = [[RequestAcceptTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: but tableview content also will be always fixed right (always 5)? because I want them to be added dynamically, as soon as a user request a ride, but its limit will always be 5 rides, starting from 0 rides til 5 rides.